# HTML5 scale canvas to fit page but keep canvas image at specific size

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I am creating specific size image of 1200W x 300H and when its done I pass the image back to my server.  I have all that working.

However, when the image is created, that 1200x300 size blows off the page for many users - especially on a mobile device.  Is there any method I can use that can create the image at the specific 1200x300 but then visually display the image on a smaller scale to fit the screen?

Currently the best I am able to do is use a DIV with `overflow:hidden` to keep the DIV correctly sized on the page, but that doesn't scale the actual image down.  In fact the image is mostly off centered only seeing the left part of the image on the screen.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;" >
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="300">
    Your browser does not support Canvas.
  </canvas>
</div>
```

If I shrink the canvas to fit the page, then the created image is the smaller size and not the size I need passed back to the server.

Is it possible to do this?

============= UPDATE ================

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;" >
   <canvas id="displayCanvas" width="1200" height="300">
      Your browser does not support Canvas.
   </canvas>
   <canvas id="realCanvas" width="1200" height="300">
      Your browser does not support Canvas.
   </canvas>                            
</div>
```

#CSS

```
#realCanvas {
  width:100vw;
  height: 25vw ;
}
```

#JS

```
function buildBanner () {
  Debugger.log("Drawing Canvas");
  
  if(!canvasSupport()) {
      return;
  }
  
  var wCanvas = 1200 ;
  var hCanvas = 300 ;
  var wImg = 400 ;
  var hImg = 100 ;
  
  var hRatio = wCanvas  / wImg    ;
  var vRatio =  hCanvas / hImg  ;
  var ratio  = Math.min ( hRatio, vRatio );
  var centerShift_x = ( wCanvas - wImg*ratio ) / 2;
  var centerShift_y = ( hCanvas - hImg*ratio ) / 2;    
  
  var displayCanvas = document.getElementById('displayCanvas') ;
  var displayContext = displayCanvas.getContext('2d');
  
  var realCanvas = document.getElementById('realCanvas');
  var realContext = realCanvas.getContext('2d');
  
  var text1 = document.getElementById('textType1') ;
  var text2 = document.getElementById('textType2') ;
  
  if (text1.checked) {
    var bannerText = document.getElementById('cVendor').value ;
    console.log("Text1: "+ bannerText) ;
  } else if (text2.checked) {
    var bannerText = document.getElementById('cVendorName').value ;
    console.log("Text2: "+ bannerText) ;
  }
  
  var textStrokeColor = "#000000";
  var textBaseline = "middle";
  var textAlign = "center";
  
  // This is the event handler for listening for a key up event in the text box form
  // It will call the textBoxChanged function to update the text in the canvas
  
  var fontSize = document.getElementById("fontSize").value;
  var fontFaceSelect = document.getElementById("fontFace");
  var fontFace = fontFaceSelect.options[fontFaceSelect.selectedIndex].value ;
  var fontWeightSelect = document.getElementById("fontWeight");
  var fontWeight = fontWeightSelect.options[fontWeightSelect.selectedIndex].value ;
  var fontStyleSelect = document.getElementById("fontStyle");
  var fontStyle = fontStyleSelect.options[fontStyleSelect.selectedIndex].value ;
  
  var fillTypeSelect = document.getElementById("fillType");
  var fillType = fillTypeSelect.options[fillTypeSelect.selectedIndex].value ;
  var strokeTypeSelect = document.getElementById("strokeType");
  var strokeType = strokeTypeSelect.options[strokeTypeSelect.selectedIndex].value ;
  
  var textFillColor = document.getElementById("textFillColor").value ;
  var bgFillColor = document.getElementById("bgFillColor").value ;
  var imageData = document.getElementById("createImageData");
  
  realContext = drawScreen(realContext,wCanvas,hCanvas,4);       
  displayContext = drawScreen(displayContext,wImg,hImg,1) ;
  
  var imageDataDisplay = document.getElementById("imageDataDisplay");
  imageDataDisplay.value = realCanvas.toDataURL();  
  
  function drawScreen(thisContext,x,y,xSize) {
    thisContext.clearRect(0, 0, x, y);
  
    var metrics = thisContext.measureText(bannerText);
    var textWidth = metrics.width;
    var xPosition =  x / 2
    var yPosition =  y / 2;

    // Draws the Text Box
    thisContext.globalAlpha = 1.0;

    thisContext.fillStyle = bgFillColor ;
    thisContext.fillRect(0,0,x,y);
    
    // Draws the actual text
    var xFontSize = fontSize * xSize ;
    thisContext.font = fontWeight + " " + fontStyle + " " + xFontSize + "px " + fontFace;
    thisContext.textBaseline = textBaseline;
    thisContext.textAlign = textAlign;

    var tempColor;
    switch(fillType) {
      case "colorFill":
          Debugger.log("Color Fill");
          tempColor = textFillColor;
          break;
      case "linearGradient":
          Debugger.log("Linear Gradient");
          var linGradient = thisContext.createLinearGradient(xPosition-textWidth/2, yPosition, xPosition+textWidth/2, yPosition);
          linGradient.addColorStop(0, textFillColor);
          tempColor = linGradient;
          break;
      case "radialGradient":
          Debugger.log("Radial Gradient");
          var radGradient = thisContext.createRadialGradient(xPosition, yPosition, 1, xPosition, yPosition, textWidth/2);
          radGradient.addColorStop(0, textFillColor);
          tempColor = radGradient;
      break;
    }

    switch(strokeType) {
      case "fill":
          thisContext.fillStyle = tempColor;
          thisContext.fillText(bannerText, xPosition, yPosition);
          break;
      case "stroke":
          thisContext.strokeStyle = textStrokeColor;
          thisContext.strokeText(bannerText, xPosition, yPosition);
          break;
      case "both":
          thisContext.fillStyle = tempColor;
          thisContext.fillText(bannerText, xPosition, yPosition);
          thisContext.strokeStyle = textStrokeColor;
          thisContext.strokeText(bannerText, xPosition, yPosition);
          break;
    }
    return thisContext ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by listening to a `resize` event and manipulating the CSS width & height properties accordingly but there's an easier way if your `<canvas>` element is always the same size.

To understand what's going on you need to know that the width & height set via the canvas' elements own attributes is the 'real' resolution of the canvas. What size is actually rendered on screen can be controlled by the CSS width & height properties.

What we want to do is scale the canvas to fill the browser's available vertical viewport **and** scale it's height while maintaining the canvas' original aspect ratio.

First we need to calculate it's aspect ratio: `300 / 1200 = 0.25` which means it's height is 1/4 of it's width. In plain english we want to make the canvas width 100% the viewport's width and it's height 25% the viewport's width.

Luckily this transfers directly to the CSS `vw` unit. e.g. `100vw==100% viewport width`.

So all you have to do is setting the canvas CSS width to `100vw` and it's height to `25vw`.

Here's an example:

```js
let image = new Image();
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
image.onload = (e) => {
  context.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
image.src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/10/1200/300';
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="300">
    Your browser does not support Canvas.
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not able to get this to work when creating an image from scratch.  The image created is from user input, text, colors, font, etc.  Really, all it looks like is the wrapper DIV has the width/height set using `vw` - which is what I added to my CSS for the DIV, but the 1200x300 image is not scaling down.  What more can I provide you in the OP?

Comment: What I have done temporarily is create two canvas - one at real size (1200x300) and one at 25% (400x100).  I display the smaller one, hide the real one - and when the form is submitted, send the `realCanvas.toDataURL();` to the server.  Its not pretty, but so far its the only thing I can get to scale down the full size image.

Comment: Without seeing your actual html layout this is more like fishing in muddy waters I'm afraid. It sounds like though you've applied the `100vw` `25vw` to the wrong element as you said 'wrapper DIV'. The `<canvas>` element needs those styles.

Comment: it is applied to the canvas, though you are right, my comment did imply it was applied to the wrapper DIV, sorry about that.  The `displayCanvas` / `realCanvas` is my temp solution that is working, the CSS is applied to `realCanvas` - but its not scaling down.  I posted all my code in an update in the OP.

Comment: Could you link e.g. a fiddle showcasing this issue? I've tested my solution (and even your code) in various browsers now and it was working flawlessly!

Comment: There should be no need to create a "real" canvas and a "display" canvas.  The image you get from `toDataURL()` should be exactly the same. CSS is only used to display the canvas smaller in the browser, it scales down the display but not the actual size.

Comment: Another way to shrink down the canvas display while maintaining aspect ratio is to apply a CSS transform: `#mycanvas { transform:scale(0.4) } `

Comment: thanks guys, I hear ya.  the dual canvas shouldn't be needed, but because I couldn't the CSS working - or thought scaling won't work - I came up with the dual solution.  Gonna keep plugging at this to try to get the CSS to scale it.

Comment: @obscure @kokodoko - I got it work simply by applying `width:25vw;` directly to the canvas. No need for a height...when I did `width:100vw;height:25vw` the image didn't change - which was throwing me off thinking it wasn't working.  It was, it just wasn't changing the scale.    The `transform:scale(0.25)` also worked, but that centered the canvas to the wrapper DIV - and I needed it to the left margin of the DIV....with `width:25vw;` it was perfectly aligned to the left of the DIV.

Comment: Yes just setting the width but not the height is also a good solution. As long as you don't use two canvases :) By the way you can change the transform center as well, for example: `transform-origin: top left;`